# Magento2 - adding notice under counry_id field in checkout

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1.3

So Im trying to add notice under country_id, I tried the following layout in checkout_index_index.xml:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Some note here</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Select Field</item>
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
                                                        </item>                                                                                                                         
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Only thing i could update, is the field order

**Cant update the notice or the label...**

How can this be done?